# Best way to access controls on parent page from a child page popup?

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0

I have a parent ASP.NET page which has a link that opens a child ASPX page in the form of a popup.

I need to control the parent page from the popup page's code-behind. For example  enablie/disable the visibility of a label in the parent page, or setting text value for a text box.

How can I accomplish this?

**Code used to open the popup ASPX:**

```
//JavaScript function:
function showPopup()
{
     var strReturn = window.open("TaxReportInputsForm.aspx",'popup','width=390,height=120');
}
```

**Button code:**

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "popup", "showPopup();", true);
```

Comment: Can you shown us how you display the popup? (e.g. do you use JavaScript)

Comment: Sure .. I've added the popup code ..

Comment: **Everyone:** Please **don't** close this thread .. This is a proper question, so I'm not sure why people are voting to close this question ... No reason for the vote has been stated too .. I really need the answer here ..

Comment: Don't worry, this question looks fine now that its been edited so it shouldn't be closed :)  If you see a question of yours getting close votes its usually an indication that there is something that needs improving before other users will be able to answer it - either try reading through you question again to see if you can spot what the problem is, or if you can't see any problems yourself you can post a comment asking for advice on how you can improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you have is that HTTP is stateless and so each HTTP request/page is handled entirely independently - this means that there is no way to **directly** modify what is rendered on the parent page while processing a request from the child page.

What you can do however is *indirectly* modify what is rendered by having the child write out some flags/information to some place that both the child and the parent page can access, and then having the parent page look at that information to determine what to render.  There are loads of different places that you could store this state, e.g.

- [Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Session variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (i.e. in memory on the server)
- In a hidden field / query string in the page

For example, your child page might write a `ShowSomeLabel` flag to a cookie in the code-behind, then when the child page returns to the client it forces a refresh of the parent page, then in the code-behind for the parent page it can read that flag from the cookie to determine what labels should be visible.

All of these methods will require at least *some* JavaScript to cause of refresh of the parent page, however some will need additional JavaScript to copy hidden field / query string values from the child page to the parent page before it submits.  Exactly where and how you should store this information depends on your specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use javascript, 
suppose A.aspx is parent page and B.aspx is the open page,
you can use "opener" to contronl DOM of A.aspx.

A.aspx link tag and javascript :

```
<a href="B.aspx" target="_blank">open page B</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fun_A() {
        alert("hello");
    }
</script>
```

B.aspx

```
<input id="btnChild" type="button" value="call function in Page A" onclick="opener.fun_A();" />
```

when you open B.aspx from A.aspx, and click the button from B.aspx, 
you will see A.aspx alert message "hello".

hope this can help you.

Comment: I cannot do it through JavaScript .. Technically it can be done probably, but the controls I have to enable/disable in the parent form are somewhat complex, so doing it using code-behind would be much easier ..